# can we exclude a particular file alone while building apk in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-productflavors, flutter-build

There is 2 product flavour in my project and i do not want some files to be added while building the **.apk** or app bundle and the below solution is not working .

```
android {
 packagingOptions {
            exclude 'lib/widgets/hotel.dart'
            exclude 'lib/widgets/hotel_list_view.dart'
            exclude 'lib/widgets/hotel_list_data.dart'
            exclude 'lib/widgets/smooth_star_rating.dart'
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to worry about that the files which are not used will automatically removed from the code